# Custom figure insertion in tex document

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a report of 3 pages - the first page and the quarter of the second page have texts. I have to include a figure which needs another page.

The problem: Figure is appearing only on the 3rd page while I am trying to bring it to the second page and the remaining texts on the third page. The `\begin{figure}[ht!]` option is not working. I am sure there must be a little trick, but what is it?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) required to produce this, and provide a link to (or possibly hardcode the dimensions of) the image. It may be that there is not enough room after the initial text on Pg2 to fit the figure in.

Comment: @pban92 You do not need to float the figure in this case. Just use `\includegraphics` on its own no need to enclose between `\begin{figure}` etc..

Comment: @pban92 You could try `H` as the place specifier

Comment: This question is frequently asked in slightly different form. See for example [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned) and the other questions linked there on the sidebar to the right.

Comment: @Edd, yes there is no enough room on the second page. So looking for a way to 'swap' the figure and texts. Well, minimal working wont be possible here as this is a part of my thesis. I was trying to find the option. Thanks!

Comment: @pban2 Is it possible to replicate the problem using something like the `[blindtext](ctan.org/pkg/blindtext)` package to insert dummy text and a similarly sized placeholder image? This would mean we'd have a MWE to understand the specifics of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package is useful for such cases:

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
...
\afterpage{\clearpage}
% place this command on the first page enforcing figure output on the second page
```

Answer (score 0):

The `placeins` package provides a `\FloatBarrier` macro which will stop any previously declared floats to be placed after it. However, in your case this might lead to an extra float-only page.